# Looking for a trick to solve $2\sqrt {2x}+\sqrt {2x+3}=\sqrt {3x+2}+\sqrt {6x+20}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the equation:

$$2\sqrt {2x}+\sqrt {2x+3}=\sqrt {3x+2}+\sqrt {6x+20}.$$

**Find a trick** ( if exists ) which allows to solve it **elegantly** i.e. with avoiding  the  systematic squaring.

(The systematic squaring inevitably leads to a fourth-degree equation:

$$
\begin{align}
0
&=
207x^4-12564x^3+27738x^2+231084x-40401\\[6pt]
&=9\left( 23x^2-1258x-4489\right) \left( x^2-6x+1\right)\;,
\end{align}
$$
so the answer is 
$$x=\dfrac {629+\sqrt {498888}} {23}.$$

Comment: You announce an equation, but what you write is two different expressions for one side of the equation, the other side of which is presumably meant to be $0$?

Comment: OK, I have fixed it...

Comment: Why do you think there is a trick? Also, why just the one answer? $x^2 - 6x+1$  has two positive roots, $3 \pm \sqrt 8.$

Comment: @Will You can check with mathematica that there exist unique solution here

Comment: @Will: The squaring can introduce spurious solutions, since the squared equation is satisfied even if the unsquared one had the wrong signs. I get the same quartic when I do the squaring with Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: Alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2sqrt%282x%29%2Bsqrt%282x%2B3%29-sqrt%283x%2B2%29-sqrt%286x%2B20%29%3D0 shows only the one real solution

Comment: You want an elegant way to get to $\sqrt{498888}$. I can't imagine such a thing exists.

Answer (score 1):

1. This equasion is defined for all $x>0$.
2. Function *on the left hand side* is strictly increasing (i.e always increasing).
3. Function *on the right hand side* is strictly increasing (i.e always increasing) too.

We can draw a simple graph on large scale, but with low prescision, to find out where too look for this root. We'll see on the graph that there is 1 intersection. Beacuse both functions strictly increasing there will be no other roots for $x>0$.

You [can use this](http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/) or any other tool to draw two graphs for left and right hand side functions.

From that graph we'll see that $x \in (58.02 , 58.08)$. You can get the decimal answer depending on the prescision required by incrasing prescision of interval ends.

Comment: @RossMillikan, I agree, I edited my answer.